# Get all data with owner = value From json code with php

Tags: php

i want get all objects with owner = true

i have made code that get specific data from json array 
so when i print  id to find it give me the last one i want it print  all owner value = true
i did try foreach but give me error
so any one can help me

```
    {  
       "owner":true,
       "number":2146958847,
       "ser":"333",
       "id":"505417057861500987",
       "name":" test"
    },
    {  
       "owner":true,
       "number":2146958847,
       "ser":null,
       "id":"506154122521608196",
       "name":"test1"
    }

]
```

my code

```
<?php $o1 = json_encode($_SESSION['guilds']);
    $arr  = json_decode($o1,true); 
$username = array();

$len = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $id = $arr[$i]["id"];
    $owner = $arr[$i]["owner"];
    $isowner[$owner] = $id; 

}

$thisisowner = true;
if(isset($isowner[$thisisowner]) ){

    $idToFind = $isowner[$thisisowner];

    echo $idToFind;

}else{
    echo "this owner doesn't exist";
}
?>
```

output for this code = `505417057861500987`

i want to be like this =

```
id: 505417057861500987 - Number : 2146958847 | name : test1 ,id : 506154122521608196 | Number : 2146958847| name : test
```

not one

Comment: If `$_SESSION['guilds']` is an Array or an Object already...... Why are you converting it to JSON and then back again to an Array???

Comment: Where is `$usernameToFind` set? What is the purpose? You indicate that you're expecting multiple values/lines output, but it is not clear _how_ you're expecting that to happen. You are checking if a certain index is set on an array. Where do the _multiple_ values come into play?

Comment: it show me a lot of errors if i did not do that

Comment: Then show us a `var_dump($_SESSION['guilds']);` please

Comment: array(29) { [0]=> array(5) { ["owner"]=> bool(false) output in array

Comment: `$isowner[$owner] = $id;` This will never work, as you set `$owner = $arr[$i]["owner"];` which is not unique, only has a value of true or false

Comment: so how i solve that ?